# castle windsor passing parameters

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a DI container and I want to pass in arguments to the constructor, via the DI container.

ie,

```
public interface IPerson { }

public class Person : IPerson {
    private int _personId;

    Person() { _personId = 0; }
    Person(int id) { _personId = id; }
}
...
Container.Register(Component.For<IPerson>().ImplementedBy<Person>().Lifestyle.Transient);
...
//Person is already available
Container.Resolve<Person>(55);

//Person is not available
Container.Resolve<Person>();
```

This is basically what I want to do.  Sometimes I need a new class created, sometimes I already have the class available.  How would I achieve this please?

I have thought that I might be able to use dynamic parameters, but I am not sure how.

Thank you in advance.

---

A Factory pattern would make the solution elegant, however, this adds a bunch of complexity to my application, when all that is needed is a very simple solution which will work just as well.

Passing in a single integer in myself is far far easier than writing a whole factory to do the same job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous type to the `Resolve` method which specifies the parameter values to use:

```
container.Resolve<IPerson>(new { id = 5 });
```

However, if you creating instances of `Person` at various points in your application, then you don't want to be referencing the container, so you should use a `PersonFactory` instead which resolves via the container. Have a look at the [Typed Factory Facility](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility.ashx).

Comment: I should have realised this was the way, it was staring me in the face.  Thank you.

Comment: This page has moved: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility.md

Answer (score 1):

this is my example how to pass params to constructor (DI contailer is unity):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

     container.RegisterType<ILogger, FileLogger>(new InjectionConstructor(new[] { "c:\\myLog.txt" }));
     ILogger logger = container.Resolve<FileLogger>();
     logger.Write("My message");
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

According "Sometimes I need a new class created, sometimes I already have the class available. How would I achieve this please?" - try to implement [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) Pattern

Comment: I believe I would be using something like  ILogger logger = container.Resolve<FileLogger>(@"C:\\LogPath");

Comment: Yes, it's also can be used this way